QT embedded external window focus not working as intended
I'm developing a Windows application and I need to embed an external window (of which I have almost no control, so editing the external app is not a reliable option). I'm currently doing it like:
//After founding the WId of the desired window...
QWindow* window = QWindow::fromWinId(id);
embedding = QWidget::createWindowContainer(window, ui->game);
//Some more specific things...
embedding->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
embedding->setFocusProxy(ui->game); //I explain this later

ui->game->layout()->addWidget(embedding);
ui->game->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);

where ui->game is  a widget situated in the top-right corner of the screen (I want the window to be displayed there).
The window shows in the right place and everything is OK, but the embedded window does no longer take focus when clicking on it and input (such as keyboard input) doesn't work on it.
I'm currently trying to get the focus to the ui->gamewidget, and from there make the window focused using Win32 functions, but I don't know if this is even possible, or if there exists a better way to do this.
I have tried to define a focusInEvent over ui->game that sets the focus to the window
void GameWidget::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* event)
{
    qDebug() << "Focused in";
#ifdef __WIN32
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_ACTIVATE, true, 0);
    SetFocus(hwnd);
#endif
    QWidget::focusInEvent(event);
}

and it works, but the focus to ui->gameis only detected when clicking in the margins of its layout (not in the embedded window itself). This is why I had embedding->setFocusProxy(ui->game); before, but it doesn't work. I also tried to set some flags to the window
window->setFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::ForeignWindow);
window->setFlags(Qt::WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus | Qt::WindowTransparentForInput);

Tried to create a custom QWindow that reports whenever it gets focus/clicked in:
class EmbeddedWindow : public QWindow
{
private:
    HWND hwnd;
public:
    EmbeddedWindow() : Qwidget()
    void setHwnd(HWND hwnd)
    {
        this->hwnd = hwnd;
    }
protected:
    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* event) override
    {
        qDebug() << "Focused in";
    }
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        qDebug() << "WINDOW Mouse event";
    }
};

and redefine my window as
EmbeddedWindow* window = (EmbeddedWindow*)QWindow::fromWinId(id);
and removed the previous flags, but i dind't get anything from this in the debug console, so I have ran out of ideas.

The official purpose of createWindowContainer() is to allow embedding of foreign windows that are based on Qt (eg: QtQuick views), and even in that case it has lots of known limitations. Embedding windows created in any other way is unsupported: it will almost certainly work in unexpected/unreliable ways, and in some cases it will just not work at all, depending on the OS, its configuration, and how the foreign window/toolkit is implemented.

After almost two days thinking, I did a trick that solved the issue (at least, for Windows platforms, I think).
    hwnd = (HWND)id;
#ifdef __WIN32
    SetParent(hwnd, (HWND)this->window()->winId());
    SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP);
#endif

    QWindow* window = QWindow::fromWinId(id);

In this way, I use OS functions to set the window as a child of the main QT Window, and then setting its style to WS_POPUP to remove all kinds of frame, title or buttons, it looks like a borderless window. Then just
    embedded = QWidget::createWindowContainer(window, ui->game);
    embedded->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    embedded->setFocusProxy(ui->game);

as usual so that the window gets displayed in the layout, and everything works fine. I don't know if there is a better workaround, but this works in case someone needs it (in Windows).
